# Why is data exchanged between my two web apps using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post cannot be trusted, even when using HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, redirect, saml, openid-connect

Why is data exchanged between my two web applications using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post cannot be trusted by each web application, even when using HTTPS?

**Note:**

I understand that data exchange using query parameters has inherent security **risks like CSRF, leaking of data via browser history and access logs**, and **auto-form-post has inherent CSRF security risk**. However, that is not the point of discussion here. Lets assume that we mitigated CSRF. The question at hand is, **"Why can't each web application trust the exchanged data, even with HTTPS?"**

**Use Case:**
Consider two web applications running on https://one.abc.com and https://two.xyz.com. They both desire to exchange data but cannot communicate directly.

**Detailed Flow:**
Upon visiting https://one.abc.com, a page displays a button. When clicked, it submits to https://one.abc.com, then redirects to https://two.xyz.com. On https://two.xyz.com, another button exists, which when clicked, submits to https://two.xyz.com and redirects to https://one.abc.com.

As everything occurs over HTTPS, all elements including URLs, query parameters, and headers are encrypted during redirection.

With this setup, data exchange between the two web applications can be achieved using query parameters or auto-form-post.

**However, why can't each web application trust the exchanged data, even with HTTPS?**

In simpler terms, during the first step, if `https://one.abc.com` sends data using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post to `https://two.xyz.com`, `https://two.xyz.com` cannot trust that the data indeed originated from `https://one.abc.com`, even when HTTPS is used.

Similarly, during the second step, if `https://two.xyz.com` sends data using redirection with query parameters or auto-form-post to `https://one.abc.com`, `https://one.abc.com`  cannot trust that the data indeed originated from `https://one.abc.com`, even when HTTPS is used.

***The above technique is used in SAML, OIDC for SSO.***

**Please let me know if my following understanding is correct:**

In the described redirect flow from `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com` and back to `one.abc.com`, the TLS (Transport Layer Security) encryption is established separately between your browser and each server involved. Let's break down the flow:

**From `one.abc.com` to `two.xyz.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `one.abc.com`, your browser initiates a request to `one.abc.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `one.abc.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `two.xyz.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `two.xyz.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `two.xyz.com`.

**From `two.xyz.com` back to `one.abc.com`:**

- When you click on the button on `two.xyz.com`, your browser initiates a request to `two.xyz.com` over HTTPS (HTTP over TLS).
- `two.xyz.com` responds with a redirect response (HTTP 302 Found) instructing your browser to go to `one.abc.com`.
- Your browser then initiates a new HTTPS request to `one.abc.com`, establishing a separate TLS connection between your browser and `one.abc.com`.

Each of these connections (from your browser to `two.xyz.com` and from your browser back to `one.abc.com`) is encrypted using TLS independently. The TLS encryption ensures the confidentiality and integrity of the communication between your browser and each server, protecting the data exchanged during the redirect flow.

However, there's no direct TLS connection established between `two.xyz.com` and `one.abc.com` during the redirect flow. Instead, the HTTPS connections are terminated and re-established separately at each server endpoint.

For this reason in SAML, IDP signs the `SAML assertion` and in OIDC, OIDC Provider signs `id_token`.

Comment: *"Please review the below answer and let me know if my understanding is correct."* - that's not how this site works. If you have a question about your understanding then put your current understanding in the question and not in an answer. Also, this kind of question is better asked at [security.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I deleted the answer and added my answer to question. I initially did the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78163950/why-data-exchange-using-redirection-via-query-params-auto-form-post-cannot-be-tr and Nick asked me to add it as answer.

Comment: I've reformulated your question to make it more clear that you want a verification of your understanding. But again, this is better asked at [security.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich can you please help me out with the question link on https://security.stackexchange.com/? I am not able to find it.

Comment: This is borderline incoherent gibberish.

Comment: @GregAskew The actual question I have is why, in OIDC, the `id_token` must be signed by the OIDC provider, and the client must verify the `id_token`, even when the `id_token` is exchanged over the front-channel using HTTPS.

Comment: You are asking a question to the mirror, seeking validation that this blathering is meaningful. You describe nothing in particular unusual, any web service can use query parameters or form parameters.

Comment: Homework that went off track.

Comment: @GregAskew may be you did not understand but others did understand the question and did answer. May be you did not read the question completely or you think it is so basic that you dont need to answer. Anyways I got the answer I need from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot trust any data passed from a client (potential attacker).

Essentially, a redirect causes a client to change the server. Depending on the application, data may be carried over *by the user*.

If there's no way to verify that data, an attacker may forge any of it. Likewise, a referrer that you might use to verify the redirect is another piece of data that may be forged without effort.

Using encryption with HTTPS doesn't change that. HTTPS encrypts data between a client and a server but it doesn't verify the origin of that data. An attacker *between* client and server can't read or change the passed data, but if the attacker is the client then SSL doesn't help a bit.

Reliable methods require either a secure data exchange between servers or cryptographic signing of the data passed by the client.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Zac67. From your response I am assuming you are confirming my answer "For this reason in SAML, IDP signs the SAML assertion and in OIDC, OIDC Provider signs id_token."